# Updating the database item from FirebaseRecyclerAdapter android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

Using the default `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` for showing a list of items from a firebase query, is there a way to update a chosen item from inside the `Adapter`.

More specific, for example when a user clicks a like button the items' node in the realtime database should be updated and also the `ViewHolder` of it  the app .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this, i needed just to get the key of the node using `mAdapter.getRef(position);` then update the node using `runTransaction`, and since `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` is live-bound it will update the view automatically.

Comment: I want to do pagination with `FirebaseRecyclerApdate`, is this useful? I'm not sure how to achieve this.

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean by pagination, but this is useful for getting the DatabaseReference of the item in adapter with the specified Position.